# Swift Package Manager BuildToolPlugin Network Access

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm experimenting with the new `BuildToolPlugin` for Swift Package Manager.

Evolution: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0303-swiftpm-extensible-build-tools.md

I have found, as the documentation says that `network access is blocked`.

I'd quite like to download a configuration file when my plugin runs, but have no-way of doing so.
Can anyone offer any work arounds, ie:

- Can I disable the sandbox for my plugin only?
- Is there a different approach to downloading files in a plugin?
- or am I plain stuck here?

Thank you

Chris

Comment: This is probably impossible. You can pass configuration from the target that uses the plugin (a file inside the package the uses the plugin). The sandbox seem to be enforced by SPM itself. The reason is security, of course.
Note that the plugin works as a build command in Xcode. It is supposed to just take input files and produce output files, nothing else.